# Configure AFNetworking with Mac osx Application

Tags: ios, macos, xcode6, afnetworking

I am using XCode 6 with os x 10.9.5 . I am creating osx Application, where I need to do Network Operation. I have added AFNetworking Framework. In iOS I have to import Framework in .pch file, Where OSX not have that kind of File. So How do I Configure AFNetworking Framework with osx Project?

Comment: An OSX Xcode project also contains a prefix file, by default.

Comment: So how do I Import or Add AFNetworking Framework?

Comment: Import it wherever it's used, like any other header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps :

1) Create `Constant.h` file.

[image]

2) Now `import` any `framework` in `Constant.h`

3) Now `import` `Constant.h` wherever you want to `use`.

Thats it !!!!

Comment: Thank you for Your Reply, I have add #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
in ".h" file and then import that ".h" file to required file but it gives Warning like "SystemConfiguration framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Network reachability functionality will not be available."

Comment: Now import Constant.h wherever you want to use

Comment: Thank you, ".h" file not work But ".pch" file solved my issue. Now I just need to import required classes and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusing naming going on here as AFNetworking isn't really a Framework here in the Cocoa sense of the word. It's just a collection of classes.

If you look in the sample projects that come with it you will see that all you need to do is copy the class files into your project and them import the appropriate ones where needed.

[image: AFNetworking Sample Code]

Comment: Thank you, Yes you are right, I have to add required classes but Problem was that I am not able to import those classes. Now Error is solved thank you for your response.